# Perform operation on every array element pair quickly

Tags: python, arrays

I have an array A

```
A = [5,2,8,14,6,13]
```

I want to get an array where each element is added to every other element, so the first five elements would be 5 + each element, then the next four would be 2 + each element etc. 
So the result would be

```
B = [7,13,19,11,18,   10,16,8,15,   22,14,21,   20,27,   19]
```

What is the quickest way to do this without using for loops?

Note: The problem I am trying to solve involves large boolean arrays instead of integers and the actual operation is a boolean 'and', not merely addition. I have simplified the question for ease of explanation. I have been using for loops up to now, but I am looking for a faster alternative.

Comment: Show us what you have right now.

Comment: We need to establish a slow way of doing it first. What have you got?

Comment: What is it that makes you think your loops are inefficient?

Comment: I have been using for loops. So the equivalent of 
`for n in range(len(A)): for m in range(n,len(A)): B.append(A[n]+A[m])`

Comment: I was playing around with map() and reduce() and I think there's a quicker way there somewhere, but I can't quite pin it down.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use ` [itertools.combinations](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations)

```
from itertools import combinations
a = [5,2,8,14,6,13]

print [sum(i) for i in list(combinations(a, 2))]
```

No need of list(). Thanks to @PeterWood

```
print [sum(i) for i in combinations(a, 2)]
```

Output:

> [7, 13, 19, 11, 18, 10, 16, 8, 15, 22, 14, 21, 20, 27, 19]

[Demo](http://ideone.com/7TEQB0)

Comment: Thank you. This is significantly faster.

Comment: You don't need to convert the combinations to a `list`.

Comment: @PeterWood Just wondering if removing `list` improve complexity?

Comment: Using `list` added 25% to the runtime, or without `list` is 80% of the runtime

Comment: Thanks for info. I edited my answer and gave credit to you :)

Comment: Even shorter is `map(sum, combinations(a, 2))`, which is a further 20% off the speed.

Comment: @PeterWood How are you calculating those complexities?

Comment: Use [**`timeit`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html). E.g. `timeit('map(sum, combinations(a, 2))', 'from itertools import combinations;a = [5,2,8,14,6,13]')`

Comment: @PeterWood Thanks for link.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it recursively:

```
def add_value_to_rest(sequence):
    if not sequence:
        return []
    else:
        additional = sequence[0]
        return ([additional + value for value in sequence] +
                add_value_to_rest(sequence[1:]))
```

With generators, in Python 3:

```
def add_value_to_rest(sequence):
    if sequence:
        additional = sequence[0]
        for value in sequence:
            yield additional + value
        yield from add_value_to_rest(sequence[1:])
```

Or with Python 2.7:

```
def add_value_to_rest(sequence):
    if sequence:
        additional = sequence[0]
        for value in sequence:
            yield additional + value
        for value in add_value_to_rest(sequence[1:]):
            yield value
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.
I tried the recursive method and while it is marginally faster, the gain is on the order of about 2%.
The generator method looks interesting, but I am running Python 2.7 which does not have the 'yield from' built-in.
The itertools.combinations method above is closer to 50% faster.

Answer (score -2):

```
A = [5,2,8,14,6,13]
B = []
for i, x in enumerate(A):
    for l in range(len(A) - i - 1):
        B.append(A[i] + A[i + l + 1])
print B
#[7, 13, 19, 11, 18, 10, 16, 8, 15, 22, 14, 21, 20, 27, 19]
```

Comment: What is `x` doing here? if you don't use it, you can make it obvious to the reader by assigning it to `_`, e.g. `for i, _ in enumerate(A)`. That said, isn't that just `for i in range(len(A)`? And isn't your whole thing just `for i, x in enumerate(A): for xx in A[i:]`: b.append(x+xx)` ?

Comment: I was trying to avoid for loops as much as possible because of the overhead cost.